# JQuery: hiding and then showing

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

Right now what I have works but it worries me because I don't think it should.

**CSS:**

```
#logo {
    display:none;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#logo").delay(800).fadeIn(800);
```

This setup works but when exposing the logo with JQuery, shouldn't JQuery alter the CSS? Does the JQuery `fadeIn` command automatically change `display:none` to `display:inline/initial/block/`etc?

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/fadein/. "The .fadeIn() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. "

Comment: That's not the part relevant to this question (and I don't see it stated there directly either) - indeed fading sets the initial display property. Or the other way around, it adds `display: none` which is an important difference from just changing opacity as it will take the element out of document flow.

Comment: Yes, JQuery alters the css. If you use inspect element to look at the elemnt in question, you'll see it modifies the inline styling

Comment: Jquery (javascript) does alter any css you have. Adding css properties as inline int the html. Only way to (iff need) overwritte jquery css properties is using the so hated (at least for me) `!important`

Comment: @Alvaro Menéndez - True, untrue; most of the animation functions in jquery have finished callbacks in which you can do some inline-css manipulation your self to set stuff back to what ever you wanted it to be. These can be used to override default behaviors instead of using the dreaded css !important flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes jQuery assigns an inline display:block to block elements and display:inline to inline elements when using fadeIn, fadeOut, and the misc slide functions. That is why it works.